# regular expression to match many number combinations except some specific number

Tags: regex

I want to match all the number combination except some specific number.

For example, "Date: 12/27, I ate 15 pieces chicken and 60 hamburgers. I spent $11 in total."

I want 15, 60 but not 12 27 and 11, what should I do?

Sorry for the unclear description. In fact, what I need is the number that represents the quantity of some items, not DATE, not ID number, not money in the sentences. It's hard for me to extract using the regular expression such as (?!\\d+).  I just wonder whether I need to use Natural Language Processing to extract. Can anyone give any instructions or different ideas? Thanks

Comment: And what is the criterion? What have you tried to solve this? Please clarify.

Comment: Were any of the answers helpful?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear because of my anxiety. Now I rewrite the description. Can anyone give any instructions or ideas? I must consider the good choice to implement this function.

Answer (score 1):

To only match numbers that are not in dates or money, I would use the following pattern:

```
(?: (\d+) )
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/5qpu5a/2

Answer (score 0):

You really need to elaborate. What about 123, would it match 123, 3 or nothing? What about the range of the numbers? Is there any limit to how big, how small the numbers can be? Which numbers do you want to exclude? Do they share any similarities?

You generally have to be very careful when using regex and have to be aware of most (if not all) edge cases.

In your specific example, you would be better of just naming the numbers you want to include rather than those you want to exclude, something as simple as

```
([6][0]|[1][5])
```

would do.

Comment: I think OP wants to exclude numbers that represent dates and money. For example: "date: 12/27" and "$11"

Answer (score 0):

Use look arounds:

```
(?<= )\d+(?= )
```

This requires the number to be surrounded by space chars.

The *entire* match is your target (no need for groups).

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/mliePraQXu).